# Import other spreadsheets to main spreadsheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

how can i Import other spreadsheets to main sheet in google sheets?
i traid to use IMPORTRANGE function but it's not going to work it's givin me "You don't have permissions to access that sheet." is there any way to import other tap sheet to my main sheet?

Comment: Do you have access to that spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

first, you need to run standalone `IMPORTRANGE` (for each spreadsheet separately)

```
=IMPORTRANGE("id"; "sheetname!A1")
```

this will yield an "error", so next hover the cursor of your mouse above that error cell, and a box will appear prompting you to "Allow access" eg. connect your sheet.

once all sub-sheets are connected to your master sheet you can play with placing importranges into arrays `{}`